# How do I get Auth0 custom action to send Axios Requests

Tags: javascript, axios, auth0

I am trying to use custom actions with Auth0 to create a user profile in my Cloudflare KV through a Worker. I am getting an error of "Request failed with status code 503" and no logs from Cloudflare. I have ensured I have added axios as a package etc. But it isn't working for some reason, and if I do the call normally outside of Auth0 it works fine.

```
const axios = require("axios");

/**
 * @param {Event} event - Details about registration event.
 */
exports.onExecutePostUserRegistration = async (event) => {
  await axios.post("https://blahblahblah.com/createuser", { params: { "id": event.user.user_id,
  "name": event.user.name,
  "email": event.user.email,
  "image": event.user.picture }});     
};
```

UPDATE:

I am able to send requests with the cloudflare dev domain so maybe my domain is blocked?

It's just the values are outputting as null now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an issue on your servers end, have you tried changing the Cloudflare dev URL?

Comment: YES! Thank you this was it.